# twitter/Instagram-like profile deep linking

Tags: react-navigation

I'd like to match a profile like
`twitter.com/maydan2a` and another screen like
`twitter.com/home`

Right now I have the deep linking config params set up like this

`Profile: ':preferredUsername'`

`Feed: 'home'`

Profile is always picked up instead of Feed when I go this way.

I don't want to have something at the beginning like 'prof' in this config:

`Profile: 'prof/:preferredUsername'`

even though I know it's a workaround.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I was using v5 of react-navigation.

I solved it by patching one of its packages based on v6.

Turns out this issue is solved in v6 but since I use expo, instead of upgrading my expo version in order to upgrade react-navigaiton to v6 - which might break many other things - I just patched exactly what I wanted and I got the behavior I was looking for.

The relevant file lives here:
`node_modules/@react-navigation/core/src/getStateFromPath.tsx`

You want to replace parts of the sort function around line 140 with this:

`const aParts = a.pattern.split('/');`

`const bParts = b.pattern.split('/');`

```
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(aParts.length, bParts.length); i++) {
    // if b is longer, b get higher priority
    if (aParts[i] == null) {
      return 1;
    }
    // if a is longer, a get higher priority
    if (bParts[i] == null) {
      return -1;
    }
    const aWildCard = aParts[i] === '*' || aParts[i].startsWith(':');
    const bWildCard = bParts[i] === '*' || bParts[i].startsWith(':');
    // if both are wildcard we compare next component
    if (aWildCard && bWildCard) {
      continue;
    }
    // if only a is wild card, b get higher priority
    if (aWildCard) {
      return 1;
    }
    // if only b is wild card, a get higher priority
    if (bWildCard) {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  return bParts.length - aParts.length;
```